# How to test Controllers with Dependency Injections in ASP.NET Core with XUnit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I am writing my ASP.NET Core Web API and I want to start writing units tests with XUnit (I know, it's a little late for that, but hey, better later than never), but I have a little complicated Dependency Injections in here. So here is my sample **Controller** class:

```
public class UnitController : MyController {

  private readonly MyContext _context;

  public UnitController(MyContext context) {
    _context = context;
  }
}
```

And **MyContext** class:

```
  public class MyContext : DbContext {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) : base(options) {
      _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
  }
```

And my **ConfigureServices** method in **Startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"))
    .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Ignore(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)));
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  services.AddMvc();
}
```

And my poor XUnit class:

```
  public class UnitControllerTest {
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public UnitControllerTest() {
      var configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>().Object;
      var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"));
      _context = new Mock<MyContext>(dbOptions).Object;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AddUnit_InvalidModel_ShouldReturnBadRequest() {
      var controller = new UnitController(_context);
      var testUnit = new Unit();
      var result = controller.AddUnit(testUnit);

      Assert.Equal(typeof(BadRequestObjectResult), result.GetType());
    }   
  }
```

And my question is,

how to write tests properly?

Comment: That's what integration tests are for. See `TestServer` class

Comment: Ok, I will definitely check this. So, I can't write unit tests for my Controllers?

Comment: You can, but it makes little sense imho and it gets to mess when you have to mock complex stuff like http context or action/controller context

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will stay with integration tests then. Time to make so smooth TestServer

Comment: Unit tests don't really make sense for something like a controller. There's a bunch of "magic" properties like `Request`, `User`, etc. that you either have to mock or they'll be null. As soon as you start mocking all this stuff, you no longer truly know if your tests are actually good/bad or if you've simply mocked something wrong, or didn't cover a potential scenario with your mock, etc. It's best to do integration tests, using your actual `Startup` class (using the test host), which will ensure that you're testing a real world-ish scenario.